# math into logic

Tags: logic

How does one translate Godel sentence about the integers into "This sentence is not provable" and Rosser's sentence into "If this sentence is provable, there is a shorter proof of its negation".

If I write down a sentence in logic, how can one translate it into a statement about the natural integers?

Which words am I allowed to use such that it can be translated into a mathemtical statement abouth the integers?

What is a precise way to translate logical statements into mathemtical statements about integers? For instance the AND operator and "This sentence" and "X is provable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An important tool used in these types of constructions is [Gödel's β function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_%CE%B2_function).  Also these Wikipedia articles cover the main ideas:

[Gödel numbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering)

[Proof sketch for Gödel's first incompleteness theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_sketch_for_G%C3%B6del%27s_first_incompleteness_theorem)

Answer (score 4):

It's rather a long story, and the best way to understand it is probably to work your way through a proof in a logic textbook or in a popularization such as Nagel and Newman.

Comment: For those who have read Smullyan and Frankel, do you have a recommendation for second order logic?  It seems people shy away, so I would be interested in a book that talks about that (understanding that it will probably be a promoter of second order).

Comment: @Ross: the two best references for second-order logic are Shapiro's *Foundations without foundationalism* and Simpson's *Subsystems of second-order arithmetic*. There is no great reference at the undergraduate level, although a few textbooks mention it.

Answer (score 1):

The main points are these:

- you need to have a complete formalization of the language and the deductive system (i.e. the deduction rules)
- once the language is completely formalized you can define a codification which attach a number to any formal statement (aka *formula*)
- once the deductive system is formalized and the language is coded with numbers you can express all the deductive rules as complex arithmetical operations on the code-numbers
- the statement "from $A$ follows $B$ throught the deduction rules" now can be translated into an arithmetical statement of the form "from the number $Code(A)$ you can derive the number $Code(B)$ by the application of these arithmetical operations"
- so at this stage any statement about provability of formulas has been converted into a statement about numbers and arithmetics.

To carry on each of these steps several technical problems need to be solved, see the references above for the details.